# Alternative Way To Approach SQL statment If no rows exist, show all

Tags: sql, t-sql

Wondering if anyone out there might know a trick to a small sql script.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09638/3

I am looking to return only the rows that have a manual transmission and are Ford make. If no rows exist, then return all Ford make vehicles. I currently doing it using an IF EXISTs condition.  I considered using a temporary table to store the first set of data, then looking at the rowcount() (rows inserted == 0) of the table to see if I needed to insert more data.  There may be no other way to do it then my two options I described.  Maybe the community has some thought on it.

#### Example DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Cars
(
  Make varchar(50),
  Model varchar(50),
  ManualTransmission bit
);


INSERT INTO Cars
(Make, Model, ManualTransmission)
VALUES
('Ford', 'Taurus', 0),
('Ford', 'Contour', 0),
('Ford', 'Mustang', 0),
('Jeep', 'Liberty', 1),
('Jeep', 'Cherokee', 0);
```

Comment: I love SQLFiddle. But please add the necessary data here too in case SQLFiddle is down.

Comment: Great point. @Martin thanks for filling in the details ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ManualTransmission DESC) AS Rnk
         FROM   Cars
         WHERE  Make = 'Ford')
SELECT Make,
       Model,
       ManualTransmission
FROM   CTE
WHERE  Rnk = 1
```

Or another

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Make,
                       Model,
                       ManualTransmission
FROM   Cars
WHERE  Make = 'Ford'
ORDER  BY ManualTransmission DESC
```

Both of these answers exploit the fact that `ManualTransmission` is a `BIT` datatype and `1` is the maximum possible value it can have. If `ManualTransmission` is nullable then you would need to change them to

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(ManualTransmission,0) DESC
```

Or

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ManualTransmission = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

The `CASE` version would also be adaptable for more complex conditions.

Comment: The 2nd version is **"TOP 1 WITH NO TIE POSSIBLE"**

Comment: @ypercube - Why? There might be more than one manual transmission car made by Ford?

Comment: Hey, let me rephrase that. I meant +10 for the use for `WITH TIES`.

Comment: @ypercube - Ah thanks! I thought something was up with my reading of the question!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select *
from (select *,
             max(cast(ManualTransmission as int)) over (partition by make) as hasManual
      from cars
      where make = 'Ford'
     ) t
where hasManual = 0 or ManualTransmission = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a fairly cheap method?
It seems to be cheaper because it does not need to do any sorting

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT   *
            ,HasManual = SUM(CAST(ManualTransmission AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY Make)
    FROM Cars
)
SELECT Make, Model, ManualTransmission
FROM CTE 
WHERE   (Make = 'Ford' AND ManualTransmission = 1)
OR      (Make = 'Ford' AND HasManual = 0)
```

Comment: Similar plan to @Gordon's. Ideal index for my answer would be `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON Cars(Make,ManualTransmission)`. If that or equivalent NCI doesn't exist then yes they could be better.

Comment: Agreed. Didn't consider the index.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars
 WHERE Make = COALESCE('Ford', Make)
   AND ManualTransmission = COALESCE(1,ManualTransmission)
```

Comment: `COALESCE(1,ManualTransmission)` will be `1`. Always.

Comment: Agreed... in this example, but I assumed that this could may run in a stored procedure and the make and manualtransmission values would change. Bad assumption.

Comment: @PaulLiebrand the point is that `COEALESCE(some static value here, column)` will always return `some static value`, since it is not `NULL`

Comment: @Lamark I realize that, but I assumed it wouldn't be static. For example, perhaps the query is being used in a stored proc and the parameter for ManualTransmission is being passed in.  A null value being passed in would then return all values.  As I stated, it was a bad assumption.